# looking to automate a process of manipulating with very large .csv files

Tags: python, shell, csv, unix, base64

here is my dilemma.  I need to process information from large .csv files.  typical size of the file is about 200mb which results in approximately 3-4 million lines.
files contain human readable information. 5 fields.
my process originally was to take the file and sort it based on the last field

"sort -k4 -n -t, "

then split

"split -l 1000000"

however now i need to add a decode from base64 of the second field.

i used this script for testing

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} (cmd="echo "$2" | base64 --decode"; cmd | getline v;$2=v} 1' originalfilename.csv > newfilename.csv

-- while running this command on a sample file a I am getting an error message.

"sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

and the process halts.

my final output are several .csv files I use to import into Excel tabs for processing.

here are my questions:

1. why am I getting the error while running awk? is there a different command that will do what i need faster and cleaner
2. can anyone suggest a better way to process my files? im trying to stay away from java but python script may work.

i am not a professional programmer, hence my knowledge ot tools is not up to date.

any advice/assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this - check settings on ulimit and swap. (free -g) or top command for CPU and memory consumption.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205016/fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Answer (score 0):

If you can install a program, I recommend GoCSV; it's a purpose-built multi-tool for CSV, has many functions for manipulating data, including decoding base64, and it's [pre-built for a number of platforms](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases).

I mocked up a sample CSV:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,0,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,1,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,2,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,3,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,4,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,5,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,6,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,7,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,8,turnip
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,9,turnip
```

We can build up to a pipeline for:

- base64-decoding the 2nd column (which actually has to add a whole new column)
- selecting that new column and putting it back in its place (in essence, overriding the original base64-encoded column)
- renaming the new column to the old column
- sorting on the 4th column
- splitting every 1_000_000 rows

I'll start with the base64 decoding, because to do that we'll actually need to add a new column:

```
gocsv add -name New_col -t '{{ b64dec .Col2 }}' small.csv
```

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,New_col
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,0,turnip,StackOverflow
banana,U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw==,apple,1,turnip,StackOverflow
...
```

We can then use the `select` command to effecitvely replace the original column with the new column:

```
...
| gocsv select -c 1,New_col,3-5
```

```
Col1,New_col,Col3,Col4,Col5
banana,StackOverflow,apple,0,turnip
banana,StackOverflow,apple,1,turnip
```

and then rename the new column back to the old name:

```
...
| gocsv rename -c New_col -names Col2
```

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
banana,StackOverflow,apple,0,turnip
banana,StackOverflow,apple,1,turnip
```

From there, add in sorting, based on column 4, and split into CSVs, each no bigger than 1_000_000 rows:

```
...
| gocsv sort -c 4 -reverse \
| gocsv split -max-rows 1_000_000
```

(My sort is reversed because column 4 was already in ascending order.)

Here's the whole pipeline:

```
gocsv add -name New_col -t '{{ b64dec .Col2 }}' big.csv \
| gocsv select -c 1,New_col,3-5 \
| gocsv rename -c New_col -names Col2 \
| gocsv sort -c 4 -reverse \
| gocsv split -max-rows 1_000_000
```

That small 10-row mock-up is from a big mock-up of your data I made:

```
% gocsv dims big.csv 
Dimensions:
  Rows: 4000000
  Columns: 5
```

When I run the whole pipeline on the big CSV:

```
% time ./main.sh
./main.sh  21.10s user 13.55s system 165% cpu 20.951 total

% ls out*.csv
out-1.csv       out-2.csv       out-3.csv       out-4.csv

% gocsv dims out-1.csv 
Dimensions:
  Rows: 1000000
  Columns: 5

% gocsv head -n 2 out-1.csv
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
banana,StackOverflow,apple,3999999,turnip
banana,StackOverflow,apple,3999998,turnip

% gocsv tail -n 2 out-4.csv
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
banana,StackOverflow,apple,1,turnip
banana,StackOverflow,apple,0,turnip
```

Comment: thanks Zach.  
i am trying to get gocsv installed and test the pipe.  
corporate security settings are a nightmare.  ))) 

just one quick follow up questions.  does split command on gocsv names new files automatically?  from your output i see files named out-1, out-2 etc.  or there is a way to force a name?
thanks

Comment: Yes, you can specify the base name for the split-out file, checkout the docs: https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#split. And good luck with security! :)

Comment: i did both. )))
will try Monday to run the scripts and see what i get. hopefully this will be the solution.  
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[DuckDB](http://duckdb.org/) is a great tool to import all CSV files at once with the following

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT Col1,from_base64(Col2)::VARCHAR AS Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5  from read_csv_auto('file*.csv');
```

and then export them with "[Partition writes](http://duckdb.org/docs/data/partitioning/partitioned_writes)" based on the row number

Since you want to split your files at 1 million lines because of a 17-years old Excel limitation (since 2007), you might want to check with Visidata to efficiently open big file ([CSV/Excel/...](https://www.visidata.org/docs/formats/)).